# Is it allowed to ask for software advice?

Tags: discussion

I've recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu and I don't miss anything except for one program named [PhraseExpress](https://www.phraseexpress.com/). With it, you can create shortcuts for words, or fix spelling mistakes you make often, automatically.

Examples:

- yuo → you
- rfg → Rindfleischverpackungsettikettierungsgerät
- ==> → $\Rightarrow$

and stuff like that. I haven't found a replacement for it on Linux, yet.

Would it be appropriate to ask for a program similar to that on Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Software recommendation questions are fine here; we just ask that they be sufficiently specific and detailed. For example, there could be a brief description of the use case or of the features required. You have included sufficient detail in your question here about what you need the software to do, so it looks like you're all set to ask a good question about it on the main site :)

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is enough data, we're missing the most important datum: in what context does the OP expect these words to be changed? Absolutely everywhere? Only in GUI programs? Would that include the terminal?

Comment: @terdon hmm good point. It looks like the question hasn't been asked yet, but let's hope that information is included when it is

Answer (score 6):

I would not ask it on AU as there is a sister site on Stack Exchange that has software recommendations as its main goal: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

In my opinion we should not compete with that. Besides that the to goto site is https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=phrase%20express

> Would it be appropriate to ask for a program similar to that on AskUbuntu?

A finite answer needs to be possible.

The way it is asked is important as it needs to pass the close votes options like "opinion", and "lacks detail".

Yes: what software can I use to do this, this and this.
No: what is a or the best replacement for this software I use on windows/mac

Comment: However, unlike some other Stack sites like Super User and Stack Overflow, we *don't* explicitly disallow software recommendation questions that I know of, right?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds yes but the way it is asked is important. it needs to pass the close votes options like "opinion", and "lacks details".

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: Ask Ubuntu Help center:  Questions you may ask:  Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron it still matters how the question is asked. "Running third-party apps" can be a question like: "How do I run application X?" which isn't a software recommendation at all.

Comment: From my experience, it depends on what sort of mood the Mod is in. Personally, I take what Ubuntu Help says literally.

Answer (score 3):

> I've recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu and I don't miss anything except for one program named [PhraseExpress](https://www.phraseexpress.com/).
>
> [...]
>
> I haven't found a replacement for it on Linux, yet.
>
> Would it be appropriate to ask for a program similar to that on Ask Ubuntu?

In your case, this would be perfectly acceptable. Your question would then be along the lines:

*I need an application with functionality equal to "PhraseExpress"* (And then explain what PhraseExpress does..) *Is there an application for Ubuntu with a similar functionality?*

Comment: s/functionality equal to/functionality similar to/ ?